# Display iframe onclick of div

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a `div` that contains an image src via CSS and I want to display an `iframe` when the image within the div is clicked. I was able to successfully display the iframe on a simple text value by wrapping an  tag around it and writing a click function with jQuery. However, I haven't been able to get this to work with my image that's within the `div`. How does my jQuery function get called within my `div`? Do I need an `onclick` event within my `div`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#containerA").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("brand").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
  })

});
```

```css
.containerA {
  width: 140px;
  height: 99px;
}

.containerA:hover {
  background: url("img/imageB_05.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.imageA:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerA" id="containerA" style="width: 140px; height: 99px"></div>

<iframe id="brand" src="http://www.blah.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery/JavaScript or Even CSS Isn't Needed

Just HTML is needed for changing the `src` of an `<iframe>`

### Requirements

1. A link with the `[href]` of the site you want the `<iframe>` to point to.
2. The link needs a `[target]` attribute as well. Give it the `[name]` attribute of the `<iframe>` (See next step).

   > ```
   > <a href="https://example.com" target="brand"></a>
   > ```
3. The `<frame>` just needs a `[name]`.

   > ```
   > <iframe name="brand"></iframe>
   > ```

See **Demo 1**

---

There's also a jQuery version see **Demo 2**

---

### Demo 1

```css
.containerA {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 30vh;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

.containerA a {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity 1.2s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.containerA a:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.75 ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

a:first-of-type {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/5LPXSfn/Lenna-test-image.png);
}

a:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg)
}

a:last-of-type {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/tmQZgJb/68eb2df1a189f88bb0cbd47a3e00c112.png)
}

iframe {
  width: 70vw
}
```

```html
<div class="containerA">
  <a href='https://example.com' target='brand'></a>
  <a href='https://plnkr.co' target='brand'></a>
  <a href='https://codepen.io' target='brand'></a>
</div>
<iframe name="brand"></iframe>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
$('.containerA').click(function(e) {
  var url = $(this).data('url');
  $('#brand').attr('src', url);
});
```

```css
.containerA {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 30vh;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg)no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
  width: 70vw
}
```

```html
<div class='containerA' data-url='https://example.com'></div>
<iframe id='brand' src='about:blank'></iframe>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#containerA").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //use iframe id as selector
$("#brand").attr("src", $('#containerA a').attr("href"));
  })

});
```

```css
.containerA {
  width: 140px;
  height: 99px;
}

.containerA:hover {
  background: url("img/imageB_05.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.imageA:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerA" id="containerA" style="width: 140px; height: 99px">
<a href="http://something.com">xxx</a>
</div>

<iframe id="brand" src="http://www.blah.com">
```

Answer (score -1):

// div #containerA has no HREF attribute cuz its not an A tag

// this needs to be #brand and $(this) points to #containerA which doesnt have an href value

```
<div class="containerA" id="containerA" style="width: 140px; height: 99px">
   <a href="http://something.com">Something</a>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#containerA").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#brand").attr("src", $('#containerA a').attr("href"));
  })
});
```

Comment: i don't know who down voted it... but if you add a snippet, i'll upVote it as a good answer...